# Send/Receive Data using Gatttool (Bluetooth Low energy)

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am connected from Linux to microcontroller which have Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE 4.2).
Currently I can connect via gatttool (-I) and bluetoothctl,but I can't send/receive data.

I have found that its unable to use rfcomm with BLE.

How can I receive data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solve my problem and want to share with you.

After connecting to device using

```
gatttool -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -I
> char-read-uuid 2902
> handle: 0x000b     value: 00 00
```

I have enable notification by

```
 > char-write-req 000b 0100
```

And after it I have received all data sent from microcontroller.